# OpenCV - Brox Optical Flow - Exception in opencv_core244d!cv::GlBuffer::unbind

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, cuda, opticalflow

Has anyone managed to get the Brox dense optical flow algorithm in OpenCV working?

Here is some code:

```
{
    // Load images
    cv::Mat PreviousFrameGrayFloat; // Has an image in format CV_32FC1
    cv::Mat CurrentFrameGrayFloat;  // Has an image in format CV_32FC1

    // Upload images to GPU
    cv::gpu::GpuMat PreviousFrameGPU(PreviousFrameGrayFloat);
    cv::gpu::GpuMat CurrentFrameGPU(CurrentFrameGrayFloat);

    // Prepare receiving variables
    cv::gpu::GpuMat FlowXGPU;
    cv::gpu::GpuMat FlowYGPU;

    // Create optical flow object
    cv::gpu::BroxOpticalFlow OpticalFlowGPU = cv::gpu::BroxOpticalFlow(0.197f, 0.8f, 50.0f, 10, 77, 10);

    // Perform optical flow
    OpticalFlowGPU(PreviousFrameGPU, CurrentFrameGPU, FlowXGPU, FlowYGPU); // EXCEPTION
    // Exception in opencv_core244d!cv::GlBuffer::unbind

    // Download flow from GPU
    cv::Mat FlowX;
    cv::Mat FlowY;
    FlowXGPU.download(FlowX);
    FlowYGPU.download(FlowY);
}
```

I get an exception, as commented above, when I try and use the `cv::gpu::BroxOpticalFlow` object, I have the same problem with `cv::gpu::PyrLKOpticalFlow` but only the dense version not the sparse one, and `cv::gpu::FarnebackOpticalFlow` works fine...

Weird.

Entire exception is:

```
Exception at 0x7c812fd3, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) in opencv_core244d!cv::GlBuffer::unbind
```

I'm using a debug build with debug libraries, using OpenCV 2.4.4 however the code also raises an exception in OpenCV 2.4.3.

When I use OpenCV 2.4.3 I get this exception:

```
Exception at 0x7c812fd3, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) in opencv_core243d!cv::SparseMat::erase
```

Comment: Is there a demo application or anything that demonstrates the usage of this calculation included with OpenCV? It may be a good place to start...

Comment: I've found this, but I was hoping there would be a solution that didn't involve recompiling OpenCV... http://stuartjames.info/Journal/opencv-brox-optical-flow-sample-possible-fix.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with other versions of OpenCV and following the information contained here: http://stuartjames.info/Journal/opencv-brox-optical-flow-sample-possible-fix.aspx

It looks like I need to recompile OpenCV with OpenGL.

It seems that you can test whether your install of OpenCV has OpenGL by running the command: `cv::gpu::setGlDevice(0);` if this fails with a weird exception like the one above then you need to recompile.

OpenGL is required as the newer optical flow algorithms in OpenCV map data to OpenGL textures to (I assume) speed up operations, or maybe to just make the code simpler.

So, after all this, the solution is to recompile OpenCV with OpenGL. This can be achieved by ticking the `WITH_OPENGL` box when using CMake to configure the build.

If you want to use the GPU version of the video reader make sure you also tick `WITH_NVCUVID` this is included with CUDA but not included unless you request it...

**-- EDIT --**

After the comments from *paul* I've corrected the scale factor in my code from the question.

Here is the complete code I'm testing, for *nkint*:

```
{
    // Load images
    cv::Mat PreviousFrameGray = cv::imread("Input1.png", 0);
    cv::Mat CurrentFrameGray  = cv::imread("Input2.png", 0);

    cv::Mat PreviousFrameGrayFloat; // Has an image in format CV_32FC1
    cv::Mat CurrentFrameGrayFloat;  // Has an image in format CV_32FC1

    PreviousFrameGray.convertTo(PreviousFrameGrayFloat, CV_32FC1, 1.0/255.0);
    CurrentFrameGray.convertTo(CurrentFrameGrayFloat, CV_32FC1, 1.0/255.0);

    // Upload images to GPU
    cv::gpu::GpuMat PreviousFrameGPU(PreviousFrameGrayFloat);
    cv::gpu::GpuMat CurrentFrameGPU(CurrentFrameGrayFloat);

    // Prepare receiving variables
    cv::gpu::GpuMat FlowXGPU;
    cv::gpu::GpuMat FlowYGPU;

    // Create optical flow object
    cv::gpu::BroxOpticalFlow OpticalFlowGPU = cv::gpu::BroxOpticalFlow(0.197f, 50.0f, 0.8f, 10, 77, 10);

    // Perform optical flow
    OpticalFlowGPU(PreviousFrameGPU, CurrentFrameGPU, FlowXGPU, FlowYGPU);

    // Download flow from GPU
    cv::Mat FlowX;
    cv::Mat FlowY;
    FlowXGPU.download(FlowX);
    FlowYGPU.download(FlowY);

    // Use FlowX and FlowY in further processing
    //...
}
```

Comment: Once you have managed to recompile OpenCV the examples that use Brox should work. What do you mean can I port it? My research code is in c++ and I have no intention to change that. The OpenCV code is in CUDA mostly to run on the GPU which is required for efficiency.

Comment: sorry i wanted to wrtie poSt not poRt

Comment: I've updated my answer with working code, provided that your OpenCV install has been compiled with OpenGL. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is required, but there may also be a problem with your scale parameter (50.0f). It seems too large. As I understand, this should be less than 1. If it is a large number, the algorithm fills up GPU memory quickly. Plus, it may not make sense to use an expanding (upside-down?) image pyramid. Not perfectly sure though.

Comment: Well I got those values from one of the examples I think, but if that's the case it would definitely be an issue. I'll have a play and see what happens.

Comment: Yep you're exactly right. When I grabbed my values from the example I got the gamma value and the scale value the wrong way around. `cv::gpu::BroxOpticalFlow OpticalFlowGPU(0.197f, 50.0f, 0.8f, 10, 77, 10);` works.